# Load large data without iterators or chunks

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, machine-learning, large-data

I want to learn on a large file of data (7GB) : 800 rows, 5 millions columns. So I want to load these data and put them in a form I can use (2D list or array).

The problem is here, when I load the data and try to store them, they use all my memory (12GB) and just stop at row 500.

I heard a lot about how to use this kind of data, like using chunks and iterators, but I would like to load them entirely in the memory so I can do cross-validation.
I tried to use pandas to help me but the problem is the same.

Is there some issues to load and store the entire 7GB of data as I want to ? Or any other idea that could help me ?

Comment: Do you have 12 GB of RAM left after subtracting whatever other resources are using?

Comment: Anyway, if you really want to load everything into memory, but don't have enough memory, the answer is to buy more memory. Or compress the data somehow.

Comment: depend on what you want to do. on way is split data to parts then load one part each time.

Comment: @timgeb is correct. you state you want to load everything into memory at once. chunking/iterating (with a generator reading the data in for example) will change nothing since in the end, it's all going to be in memory. You need to either insert more RAM, rethink your solution, or get ready to waste time thrashing away in swap space.

Comment: well, you can build up a cluster and run [Apache Spark](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/running-on-yarn.html) on it, using [Spark DataFrames](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#dataframes) which is pretty similar to Pandas. After that you should be able to process your data frames on the distributed system in parallel

Comment: I'll ask for more RAM then, thank you you saved me a lot of time

Answer (score 0):

You can try getting a swap or page file.  Depending on your operating system, you can use virtual memory to allow your system to address more objects in a single process than  will fit in physical memory.  Depending on how large the [working set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_set) is, performance may not suffer that much, or it may be completely dreadful.
That said, it is almost certain that getting more memory or using some partitioning strategy (similar to what you are calling chunking) is a better solution for your problem.

On windows take a look [here](http://www.mcci.com/mcci-v5/support/howtos4.html) for information on how to adjust page file size.   For Redhat Linux try [this link](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/3/html/System_Administration_Guide/s1-swap-adding.html) for information on adding swap.